# Cannot open redirect link in facebook iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, redirect

I have a problem with the facebook iphone app. I post a link in the wall in my facebook account and I used my iphone 4 to check it. The link I posted redirects to another page. I started the app and saw my wall and when I clicked the link, it crashes and put me out of facebook and not Safari is opened. 
This thing did not happen before and now it happens only with links that has redirection.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the application has crashed.
if you dont try reinstall firstly remove and reinstall application in iTunes.
when you've reinstall please sign in another account and try redirect link.
check safari's permission setting.

or

use safari and log in facebook mobile. below the page the was a link like download for iphone. download this and try login with app.

I hope you solved the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. I reinstall facebook app and works fine now. Thanks again